# Style anchor tag with specific value in the href attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I target all `<a>` tags that all have a specific value in their href attribute for styling using css?

Example: all the `<a href="http://www.google.nl"></a>` Tags

Comment: Modify them to what?

Comment: I have rewritten your question to be more clear and concise. Considering the answer given, I am *guessing* that by "modify" you mean "style". If that is incorrect, please feel free to rewrite your question again in your own words.

Comment: No, correctly edited, thanks. Didn't really know how to explain it exactly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly then you can [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwpwxm4t/)

```css
a[href="a"]{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<a href="a">dfdf</a>
<a href="a">dfdf</a>
<a href="a">dfdf</a>
<a href="a">dfdf</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I can't solve it now, will do it in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse.
**Style Links Depending on Destination:**

```
a[href^="http://"] {
        /* fully valid URL, likely external link */
}

a[href="http://google.com"] {
        /* link to specific website */
}
```

### EDIT:

Here is a snippet where [google.com](http://www.google.com) will have another color than the other links:

```css
a[href^="http://"] {
        color: blue;
}

a[href="http://www.google.com"] {
        color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-links">
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google</a><br/>
   <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Link to Stackoverflow</a><br/>
   <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Link to Yahoo</a><br/>
</div>
```